# Should partial (spearman) correlation be used on a time series data?

Tags: time-series, spearman-rho, partial-correlation

I'm trying to adapt my workflows to timeseries datasets and stumbled across this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpAf4N582bA

It discusses partial correlation and it seems like a useful tool for investigating timeseries data where you can use the timepoint as the covariate for partial correlation:

https://pingouin-stats.org/build/html/generated/pingouin.pairwise_corr.html

**My question is if this is a typical way to identify monotonic relationships (if using spearman) between covariates in a timeseries data if you use timepoints as the reference covariate. If not, why doesn't this work and what should I try out instead?**

Timepoints are represented as days from t=0.

Comment: What is your "workflow"?  What about time series do you want to investigate?  What would z-scores have to do with any of this (they don't change Pearson or Spearman correlations)?  Indeed, what is a "z-score normalized timepoint"??

Comment: I've normalized all my continuous covariates by subtracting the mean and dividing by stdev. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Comment: But those aren't "timepoints," are they?  And -- again -- those changes don't affect *any* kind of correlation.

Comment: I have N samples each with a different timepoint.  I have M covariates that I would like to find relationships between while accounting for time.

Comment: It is painful to hear from that YouTube video that the presenter believes regression is causal.

Comment: I understand the difference between causality and correlation but I'm looking for methods I can try to look at associations between features that are time ordered.

Comment: @Galen do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am confused about why you would use z-scores before computing the Spearman correlation. The z-scoring is a monotonic transformation, and the ranking in Spearman's correlation is invariant to everything except changes in order. Maybe I need to think more about the partialing part, but what is gained here?

Comment: @Galen I just did it to all my continuous data but I understand it doesn't make a difference.  I removed it since it seemed to distract from the actual question. What about the partial correlation bit on timeseries?

Comment: You can certainly calculate partial Spearman correlation on timeseries data in the way that you describe. If it exists in the population it will be a (often [non-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution)) random variable. Offhand I don't know what useful information it would give you.